# TAP 9.21.2 Driver - An error occurred installing the tap device

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, openvpn, device-manager, signature

I have Windows 8.1 64-bit and I tried to install Betternet, but it gave me an error when trying to install the TAP driver, so I tried to install the TAP driver by itself and it gave me the same error. I even tried disabling driver signatures and it still gave me the same error. I also tried installing the driver in Device Manager itself using the INF file but it didn't work. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem ODYS wintab 10 windows 10 32 bit with Kaspersky internet security.
I paused protection but didn't help. I then removed all parts of Kaspersky and TAP installation worked. Kaspersky had added it's own Network Adaptor, Security Data Escort Adaptor, I suspect this was the problem. Removing all parts of Kaspersky removed this adaptor.